# Getting an ODBC Connection error in VB.NET when trying to connect to Teradata

Tags: vb.net, odbc, teradata

First time questioner, be gentle

I'm trying to connect to a Teradata database using ODBC. When the code was originally written it worked. We have since upgraded the ODBC drivers for Teradata.

I tried connecting using VBA (Excel) as we still have some old code lying around

VBA code (simplified)

```
private FConnection as New ADODB.Connection

sub DBConnect(DSNName as string, UserName as string, Password as string)

Set FConnection = New ADODB.Connection
FConnection.Open DSNName, UserName, Password
```

This works with no issues. It also works if I use

```
FConnection.Open "DSN=" & DSNName & ";UID=" & UserName & ";PWD=" & Password & ";"
```

So I know the ODBC connection is not an issue.

Trying the same with VB.NET

```
Dim FConnection As Odbc.OdbcConnection

try
    FConnection = New Odbc.OdbcConnection()
    FConnection.ConnectionString = "DSN=" & DSNName & ";UID=" & UserName & ";PWD=" & Password & ";"
    FConnection.Open()
Catch ex As Odbc.OdbcException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

This results in
ERROR [08001] [Teradata][socket error] (439) WSA E HostUnreach: The Teradata server can't currently be reached over this network

I've tried a number of variations on the Connection string but nothing.

EDIT: I tried using Teradata.net instead of ODBC, but all variations of that end up with a Socket Exception in System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo

Pinging the server name works without issue

Comment: If another application on the same client machine can connect using the same DSN, this is most likely a firewall issue.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019, using Server Explorer connects successfully using the same connection details as I'm using in the connection string

Comment: Problem has been solved after a massive Google-fu session. 

The issue is nothing to do with Teradata specifically its the network share that its running on. Windows 10 update 1803 disabled network services if the application is running on a server using SMBv1
So it runs fine on my C drive. Server Explorer is fine because VS is running on my C drive. 
It worked on a different fileshare (because it must run v2 or v3)
This was what led me to the answer https://www.mertech.com/blog/windows-10-version-1803-breaks-some-shared-folder-applications
Now the fun part, getting IT to listen